# Bluetooth not working in Ubuntu 18.04 LTS (beta 2)

Tags: bluetooth, atheros, 18.04

I've installed the Ubuntu Bionic Beta 2 and everything works fine but the bluetooth. In bluetooth control panel the slider is impossible to move to "on".

Output of *rfkill list* is:

```
0: hci0: Bluetooth
   Soft blocked: no
   Hard blocked: no
1: phy0: Wireless LAN
   Soft blocked: no
   Hard blocked: no
```

Output of *lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; lsusb; dmesg | grep -i blue* is:

```
03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Qualcomm Atheros AR9462 Wireless 
        Network Adapter [168c:0034] (rev 01)
        Subsystem: Bigfoot Networks, Inc. Killer Wireless-N 1202 Half- 
        size Mini PCIe Card [1a56:2003]
        Kernel driver in use: ath9k
        Kernel modules: ath9k
04:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Qualcomm Atheros QCA8171 Gigabit 
        Ethernet [1969:10a1] (rev 10)
        Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:8000 Intel Corp. 
        Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
        Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:8008 Intel Corp. 
        Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
        Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
        Bus 003 Device 004: ID 04f2:b414 Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd 
        Bus 003 Device 003: ID 0cf3:3004 Atheros Communications, Inc.                    
        AR3012 Bluetooth 4.0
        Bus 003 Device 002: ID 0b05:17c4 ASUSTek Computer, Inc. 
        Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
[   17.715399] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.22
[   17.715414] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[   17.715416] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[   17.715418] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[   17.715422] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[   17.723207] Bluetooth: hci0: don't support firmware rome 0x11020000
[   18.600648] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[   18.600649] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[   18.600651] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
```

Comment: Ok, I've notified the bug and was confirmed. Sorry for the post here, but I've seen that a lot of people had very similar problem (alack!, none of their solutions work for me).

If someone is interested in following the bug, it's here: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1764645